# i want to install angular cli but getting errors , please tell solution

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, command-line-interface, node-modules

C:\Users\Ujjwal>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm''
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ujjwal\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-12T03_05_43_431Z-debug-0.log

Give me solution for that

Comment: start by looking in the log it suggest C:\Users\Ujjwal\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-12T03_05_43_431Z-debug-0.log though it might be an isse with your npm installation

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear npm cache: Run the following command to clear the npm cache:
   `npm cache clean --force`
2. Update npm: Make sure you have the latest version of npm installed. Run the
   following command to update npm:
   `npm install -g npm@latest`
3. Reinstall Angular CLI: Try reinstalling the Angular CLI globally using the
   following command:
   `npm install -g @angular/cli`